# Why does PrintCompilation show same method twice with different byte lengths?

Tags: java, jit

Running a JVM with `-XX:PrintCompilation`, these two lines in the output caught my attention:

```
252219 6548       3       java.lang.Character::toUpperCase (6 bytes)
252220 6549       3       java.lang.Character::toUpperCase (9 bytes)
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: As-is, the question lacks details. For one there are two `toUpperCase` methods (one [without parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) and one [with a parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase(java.util.Locale))). For another, it can well be that the JIT compiler (re-)compiles a method if it deems it necessary.

Comment: @Turing85 I think you answered it (there are two methods!)

Comment: @Michael your explanation relating to OSR is verifiably incorrect. OSR compilations are marked by a percent (%) sign.

Comment: You don't need to add those edits...

Answer (score 0):

From @Turing85's comment:

> there are two toUpperCase methods (one without parameters and one with
> a parameter)